# Quoted identifier error Codefluent

Tags: codefluent, quoted-identifier

We have a QUOTEDIDENTIFIER problem with the Azure producer. We have an entity where we defined a Geography property. We created a geospatial index on that table. However, if we perform an insert or update on that table we get the followind error:

> INSERT failed because the following SET options have incorrect
>   settings: ‘QUOTED_IDENTIFIER’. Verify that SET options are correct for
>   use with indexed views and/or indexes on computed columns and/or
>   filtered indexes and/or query notifications and/or XML data type
>   methods and/or spatial index operations.

We solved the error by dropping and restoring all stored procedures of this table but set QUOTED IDENTIFIER ON now.

The problem is, every time we run the producer the stored procedures are dropped and created with QUOTED IDENTIFIER OFF. How can we solve this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure the SQL Server producer to generate `set quoted_identifier ON` at the top of the files:

```
<cf:producer name="SQL Server" typeName="CodeFluent.Producers.SqlServer.SqlServerProducer, CodeFluent.Producers.SqlServer">
  <cf:configuration quotedIdentifier="ON" ... />
</cf:producer>
```